# why is a polynomial curve that lies on the x axis known as a double zero

Tags: polynomials

In the following graph, one of the curves of the polynomial function lies on the x axis:

[image]

If this point was (0, 2) then I could say a factor of the polynomial is ${(x - 2)^2}$

Why is this a so called double zero, I am struggling to find anything on line that describes this.

Comment: Just move up the $x$ axis just a bit. There will be two intersections with the $x$ axis at $2-\epsilon$ and  $2+\epsilon$. Do you see that ? So, there two roots which are identical. So, double root. Tell me if this is clear or not.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see this.

Comment: Can you plot the function $y=(x+3)\times (x-2)^2-1$ ?

Comment: I can see that it would have a root of -3, and a double root of 2 and a y-intercept of -1

Comment: Not exactly. Try to zoom plotting between $1.75$ and $2.25$

Answer (score 0):

Because any squared number is positive, the graph just before and just after the double zero will have the same sign. This makes the curve appear to bounce off of the x-axis.